# jquery mobile : How to hide the splash screen page when press back button

Tags: jquery-mobile

My app is started with a splash screen in the page. After 5 seconds (after showing splash screen) it will navigate to next page (login page).

When we click on the back button (on device or on the app), I want to exit the application. That means it should not go back to splash screen page. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated...